# Stop cookie setting immediately on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

having an issue with some JS where the cookie is setting as soon as the page is loading, when it should only be setting when I've click to close the box.

Any help would be appreciated. Code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://resources.site.co.nz/scripts/jquerycookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a.close').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().fadeOut(1500);
            $.cookie('hidden', 'true', { expires: null});
            alert($.cookie('hidden'));
            return false;
        });
        if($.cookie('hidden','true')){
            $('#errororganinfoinchide-this').hide();
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='boxes'>
        <aside class='warning' id='errororganinfoinchide-this'>
            <a href='#errororganinfoinchide-this' class='close'><img src='http://resources.site.co.nz/backgrounds/close.png' /></a>
            <img src='http://resources.site.co.nz/backgrounds/icon_warning.png' class='messageimg' />
            <h4>Warning - Organisation Info</h4>
            <p>Sorry, there was an error opening the "Organisation Info" Box. Please try again later.</p>
        </aside>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you cleared your cache and cookies before testing again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't the line "`if($.cookie('hidden','true')){`" set the cookie instead of reading it?

It should probably be something like this instead...

`if($.cookie('hidden') == 'true'){`

Comment: Not sure if this should be listed as another question. But is it possible to get the $(this).parent().  What I mean by this is I would like to get the id of what is being closed and make that the name of the cookie. So it would be like this:
`$.cookie('#errororganinfoinchide-this', 'true', { expires: null});`